# Docker Add file

Tags: docker

I'm trying to edit a file inside an apache image. The current file path is etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf. I pulled the image added the src folder and then used the ADD command as so: `ADD ./deflate.conf etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf`

My issue is that each directory has several files in them but when I use the ADD command it deletes the contents of all the folders. Wondering how I can just add it to the directory without deleting anything. My Dockerfile is set up like this.

```
FROM wordpress:4.9.2-php7.2-apache
ADD ./src /var/www/html

ADD ./deflate.conf etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Comment: Put a trailing slash on `/var/www/html/` if you want `/src` inside that directory. You should also should have leading `/`' on `etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf` if you aren't defining a WORKDIR.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add local files to docker container. Use `COPY` like,

```
COPY deflate.conf etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf
```

same goes with adding directories.